# Can I create an FTP super user?

Tags: ftp, administrator, cpanel

So I am going to be creating websites for a couple different clients these next few months. It is imperative that I have an FTP account that has access to all the sites' files and that cannot be deleted by the clients themselves. It seems as though "special FTP accounts" fall into this category. However, it appears there can only be one of these. Is there a way my client and myself can each have an account with access to all of the site's files, while each account doesn't have the authority to delete the other?

(I am using a Mac OS 10.9.5)

Comment: FTP jailling could be an option, user only can work with his own directory(home).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, it appears FTP jailing is more about the limiting the FTP user, than the domain administrators

Comment: Basically FTP Jailling do a particular universe to each user without any posibility to see each with others.

Comment: that mean if you use cpanel for example to admin those clients even if you share the same ftp server they will not be able to look at or touch the files from other users

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge in this area, but there is only one cPanel Administrator per website right? My clients, by virtue that their email address will be linked to cPanel, will have to have sole authority over the domain. I am unable to use cPanel for these client's sites correct?

Answer (score 0):

You did not state your operating system, so I am assuming it is a Windows environment... I would recommend using Filezilla FTP Server, it is highly configurable and you can create user accounts with passwords, including varying access to directories and files, independently from your domain users. It should easily fit the needs for what you are doing.

https://filezilla-project.org/

Comment: I am using a Mac operating system, actually, but I already use Filezilla to upload files to my sites. The problem is, this involves signing in through an FTP account that is created from cPanel. Without access to cPanel (only my client will have this access), how can I, as an FTP user, have sole control over the files I upload? I don't see a way to do this from Filezilla